# IIS missing items

Tags: iis, iis-express

I have an issue with my IIS. It is not showing any of the option except Authentication. I uninstalled IIS and re-install IIS but with no luck.

[image: IIS Menu]

I have everything installed but there is no ASP.NET menu and only Authentication is showing in the IIS options menu.

[image: IIS Options]

Comment: Curious... what build-number and edition/SKU of Windows 11 are you running? Have you tried installing IIS using `dism` (via PowerShell) and checking for any errors there? Are you running IIS Manager with elevated permissions?

Comment: I am using Version 10.0.22000.708

Comment: I used "Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /All" The operation complete successfuly.

Comment: Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on ‎2022/‎02/‎10
OS build 22000.739
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.739.0

Comment: Reset IIS Manager and see if that helps, https://serverfault.com/a/207671

Comment: Expand "Internet Information Services" -> "World Wide Web Services" -> "Application Development Features" and "Common HTTP Features" to make sure `.NET Extensibility 3.5` , `.NET Extensibility 4.5` and `Static Content` are checked.

Comment: All checked as mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you can try reinstalling IIS using powershell.